# Terminal outputting: Python 2.7.16 Even though I have 3.8.2 installed

Tags: python

I installed python 3.8.2 in my mac but every time I do in my terminal:

```
python --V
```

I get:

```
Python 2.7.16
```

I think there should be my 3.8.2 version instead of the old one. Any reasons why this is happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably have both versions installed, and it's default is Python 2.  Try typing:  `python3`

Comment: Installing a new version of Python did not make it your default. Without knowing your operating system, I can't give you specific instructions, but if you're running some version of Linux, `update-alternatives` might be the command to look into. As Mr. Karzes says, you can also manually get the new version using its direct command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed Python 3, but that doesn't mean that Python 2 is gone. Either type `python3` instead of `python`, or adjust your PATH so that 3 is first.

Comment: So I'm doing python3 -V and I'm getting: "Python 3.8.2" That's it?